# How to write automated tests for Augmented Reallity for Android app?

Tags: android, automated-tests, augmented-reality, arcore

I an currently working on an AR app for Android using ARCore, and I'm asked to write automated tests for this app, but I have absolutely no idea how to test augmented reality. Are there any tools, frameworks, or just tricks to run proper tests?

Answer (score 1):

Writing Automated test for an AR application is as good as writing Automated Tests for a native android application. You can use any open source frameworks or develop your own using appium with java  or python, testNG, Maven etc. I used an open source framework called Robot framework (based on python) as it was good for my application and platform under test.

I researched appium too and unfortunately couldn't find anything specific to test and validate AR application.

The problem with me was "how to validate if the AR Experience actually showed up on the screen."

To validate this, as there was no resource identifier for the AR asset to validate if it is visible or not, i ran "adb logcat -b system com.android.my_app_packagename:E > testlogs.txt" command while i m performing the automation test and in place of validation point if the AR asset appeared or not, I parsed the "testlogs.txt" text file and checked for availability of the events if they have triggered in the logs while i performed the action. For this i need to ask my developers to log those events in the app while they developed it.

Hope this help.